# __init__() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 4 were given after refactorizing class to be under base class

Tags: python, inheritance, attr, python-attrs

I have a class that currently looks something like this:

```
import attr

@attr.s
class my_class(object):
  var1 = attr.ib(default=5)
  var2 = attr.ib(default=5)
  var3 = attr.ib(default=5)
  @classmethod
  def func(cls):
    cls(1, 2, 3)

my_class.func()
```

I need to create an abstract base class and refactor `var1, var2` to be under base class. `var3` will stay as is.

So I tried to do this:

```
import attr
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

@attr.s
class base(ABC, object):
  var1 = attr.ib(default=5)
  var2 = attr.ib(default=5)

@attr.s
class my_class(base):
  var3 = attr.ib(default=5)
  @classmethod
  def func(cls):
    cls(1, 2, 3)

my_class.func()
```

but it gives the error

```
TypeError: __init__() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

It seems I'm not calling `cls` properly here since now there's only `var3` associated with `my_class`. If I want to initialize `var1` and `var2`, how I do it in an analogous way?

Comment: FYI you don't need to list `object` explicitly in the base classes. That was only needed in Python 2.x.

Comment: Your example works for me (as expected) perfectly. Please check what you've actually run or supply more details.

Answer (score 1):

Use `attr.define`

```
import attr
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

@attr.define
class base(ABC, object):
  var1 : int
  var2 : int

@attr.define
class my_class(base):
  var3 = attr.ib(default=5)
  @classmethod
  def func(cls):
    return cls(1, 2, 3)

res = my_class.func()

print(res)
```

Comment: I read the documentation for `attr.s` and `attr.define` in https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/api.html#attrs.define and I'm not quite sure I understand what's happening under the hood. What is it doing with each decorator? My understanding is `attr.s` creates dunker methods, of which consist of a constructor?

Comment: Note that using `ABC` here is pretty pointless because it does not define any abstract methods which would prevent instantiation of the base class directly. The code `base(1, 2)` will run without issue.

Comment: `attr.s` and `attr(s).define` can be used interchangeably, the latter has just better defaults. See: https://hynek.me/articles/import-attrs/